# Wifi via UPS during loadshedding

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ups

1. The primary fibre cable and wifi box is in my landlady’s house
2. She has both the ONT and wifi box plugged into the UPS.
3. The cables to the other wifis (mine included) run from her wifi box.
4. Her wifi is on and working when the power is off due to the UPS working.
5. I also have a UPS and the wifi box is successfully powered and my device picks up the wifi signal but no internet.
6. Am I missing a link somewhere? Would love some help!

Comment: Do the cables run _directly_ from device to device, or is there an Ethernet switch in the middle?